# Delete html tags from text during xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am doing xslt transformation and I have a problem. The text that I have to transform have some html tags, but instead of < and > I have `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I want to change content from all tags from

> ici-import/issue/article/languageVersion/abstract

and transform it into a new element: abstract, deleting the html tags

That is my code I was trying to implement:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="ici-import/issue/article/languageVersion/">
        <xsl:variable name="StripHTML">
            <![CDATA[&lt;\s*\w.*?&gt;|&lt;\s*/\s*\w\s*.*?&gt;]]>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="abstract" regex="{$StripHTML}">
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ici-import>
            <journal issn="2299-3711" />
            <issue>
                <xsl:for-each select="issue/section">
                    <xsl:for-each select="article">
                        <article>
                            <languageVersion>
                                <xsl:if test="abstract != ''">
                                    <abstract>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="abstract"/>
                                    </abstract>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </languageVersion>
                        </article>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </issue>
        </ici-import>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So how does your input look? Which XSLT processor do you use? Is that escaped HTML parseable as XHTML or is it using HTML syntax like missing end tags or not quoted attribute values?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents you have escaped is an XML fragment then in XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 HE or Altova 2017 and 2018) you could simply parse the contents and push it through a mode that only copies text through.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <data><![CDATA[<section id="s1">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p style="font-size: 120%">This is some text.</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Another test</h2>
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  </section>]]></data>
</root>
```

is transformed by Saxon 9.8 HE and the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="strip" on-no-match="text-only-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml-fragment(.)" mode="strip"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <data>
    Test
    This is some text.


  Another test
  This is some text.
  </data>
</root>
```

If the contents is not XML but HTML then you could import a local copy of David Carlisle's HTML parser written in XSLT 2 and use that to parse the contents and push it through a mode that only copies text through:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:htmlparser="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array htmlparser"
    version="3.0">

  <!-- adjust to local copy of file -->
  <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="strip" on-no-match="text-only-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="htmlparser:htmlparse(.)/node()" mode="strip"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using Saxon 9.8 HE that transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <data><![CDATA[<section id=s1>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p style="font-size: 120%">This is some text.</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Another test</h2>
  <p>This is some text.
  <p>This is some other text.
  </section>]]></data>
</root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <data>
    Test
    This is some text.


  Another test
  This is some text.
  This is some other text.
  </data>
</root>
```

Of course as the HTML parser is written in XSLT 2 you can use it with any XSLT 2 processor as well, you simply need to replace `<xsl:mode name="strip" on-no-match="text-only-copy"/>` by

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="strip">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```